# Can't get SMTP address of deleted Exchange user

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server

I am trying to process an Outlook e-mail which sender is deleted from Exchange. Normally, I use:

```
mailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
```

I also have tried to use PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES, but it says that property not found for that deleted user (although working for other e-mails).
I can see sender e-mail in message headers, so this info should be there somewhere.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for Sender.Address?

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't understand what you're trying to retrieve from the mail. Please refer to my answer, HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reading the Property `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress_W` (for Unicode), the Tag num is `0x5D01001F` (DASL: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001`)

There is also the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D02001F` (`PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SMTP_ADDRESS_W`)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. Don't you know by the way any place where all those properties are documented? I tried to find it, but with no luck.

Comment: There's mapidefs.h, there's also the tool "OutlookSpy" by Dmitry Streblechenko (check out dimastr.com)